# What methods exist to compare data sets from two different types of distributions

Tags: poisson-distribution, continuous-data

I want to compare two different types of data sets how well they correlate with each other.
Lets say I have two datasets one follows a continuous distribution and another follows a poisson distribution (count based data). What approaches exist to compare such distinct data sets.

Comment: You use the terms "compare" and "correlate". Those are two very different activities (one is useful for answering questions like "which is bigger", while the other is useful for answering questions like "does variable A increase as variable B does?"). Without using either term (nor any statistical term at all, hopefully), what is it that you're trying to find out?

Comment: Well I would be more interested in the correlation part. What I have is 4 biological entities with different distributions and I want to see how they co-evolve with respect to the fifth one.

Comment: Can you explain (preferably in an edit to your question) how  correlation relates to "seeing how they co-evolve with respect to the fifth one"?

Answer (score 1):

You might like to look in to methods based on [Kullback Leibler divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence), which is an indicator (not technically a metric as it is asymmetric) of the similarity between two (potentially heterogeneous) distributions.

More generally from the perspective of analysis, if you were trying to measure asymptotic convergence between two distributions or something similar, you might want to look into concepts such as [convergence in total variation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures), which is the pointwise similarity of two distributions and is a more abstract expression of the K-L divergence.

Alternatively, if your question is around which model (i.e. which distribution) best fits a given data set, you would want to look at the likelihood ratio test - a very general method for testing which distribution a given data set likely arose from.

If you provide some more information on the problem you're working on you will get better answers as this is an extremely general question.